# Qt DirectX fxc.exe compilation line

Tags: qt, compilation, directx

I was compiling Qt, then saw in the log `"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)\Utilities\bin\x86\fxc.exe" /nologo /E VS_Passthrough2D /T vs_4_0_level_9_3 /Fh libANGLE/renderer/d3d/d3d11/shaders/compiled/passthrough2d11vs.h ../../../3rdparty/angle/src/libANGLE/renderer/d3d/d3d11/shaders/Passthrough2D11.hlsl`

It gave error `Too many files specified ('E:/' was the last one), use /? to get usage information`

it shows in the help that `/E<name>           entrypoint name`

It seems to me that it is treating the `/E` option as the path E:/ (its unfortunate I have a drive E, and many data residing in it). Is there anyway around this? is my analogy correct? some suggestions would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Having had the same problem recently, I asked colleagues about it and was advised to use MS's cmd.exe command prompt instead of MinGW's Git Bash prompt.  For some reason that worked !  I won't pretend to understand how choice of command shell can help, but apparently it does.

See also discussion of this on Qt's own forum:
https://forum.qt.io/topic/73114/building-with-mingw64-on-windows-8

Comment: Thanks, I will try that